# Creating SSL public and private key pair in iOS app

Tags: ios, iphone, ssl

I want create SSL public and private key from my ios app and then share the public key by uploading on a server. I know it is not a usual way but I need to create multiple key pairs unique to a device so for this I want to generate SSL key from iPhone app and upload it to a server. I will then use it for my future API requests. Is it even possible?

I have no idea about it and could not found any resource for this on the web.

Comment: what are you trying to achieve ? you want to use self-signed ssl certificate for https?

Comment: yes, I want to connect with my web services in a secured way but by generating it in iPhone app not on server

Comment: *I want to generate ssl key from iPhone app and upload it to a server. I will then use it for my future api requests* with public key what can you do ? you need certificate right for https ?

Answer (score 0):

Apple explains it here:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/certificate_key_and_trust_services/keys/generating_new_cryptographic_keys?language=objc

Use SecKeyCreateRandomKey and SecKeyCopyPublicKey